# Pass values from array object in Python with multiple criteria

Tags: python, arrays, json, request

I have the following code

```
import requests
import json
parameters = {
"affiliation": "cambridge university"
}
response= requests.get("https://api.ror.org/organizations", params=parameters)
print (response.json())
```

This returns me JSON object that contains an array of items - [this is the link to the result in API as its very long to paste it all here](https://api.ror.org/organizations?affiliation=cambridge%20university)

The first result in the set has a value of ‘True’. From this result I want to pass the ‘name’ and the ‘aliases’ and ‘labels’ for the ‘child’ elements.

Based on the response from the API, I want to pass something like the following for the first result which is marked as "chosen":true:

```
"name":"University of Cambridge"
"aliases":["Cambridge University"]
"label":"Cambridge University Press","type":"Child"
"label":"Cambridge–MIT Institute","type":"Child"
etc. including each of the "type":"Child" relationships
```

I’m completely lost trying to do this. I’ve tried different things but the best I can get is ‘None’. How do I move through the array, using the ‘True’ criterion and get the relevant results?

Comment: Hi @user1222447 could you provide a sample of output? I am not sure of what you want exactly. Could you also edit the json dictionary? There is an unbalance in the brackets or quotes... Thanks!

Comment: @cards - have added in some additional detail. I hope that helps to clarify but let me know if you need more info. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right. To filter the result you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests

parameters = {"affiliation": "cambridge university"}
response = requests.get("https://api.ror.org/organizations", params=parameters)

result = []
for item in response.json()["items"]:
    if item["chosen"] == True:
        d = {"name": item["organization"]["name"]}
        d["aliases"] = item["organization"]["aliases"]
        d["labels"] = []
        for r in item["organization"]["relationships"]:
            if r["type"] == "Child":
                d["labels"].append(r)
                del r["id"]
        result.append(d)

print(result)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "name": "University of Cambridge",
        "aliases": ["Cambridge University"],
        "labels": [
            {"label": "Cambridge University Press", "type": "Child"},
            {"label": "Cambridge–MIT Institute", "type": "Child"},
            {"label": "Cancer Research UK Cambridge Center", "type": "Child"},
            {
                "label": "Centre for the Observation and Modelling of Earthquakes, Volcanoes and Tectonics",
                "type": "Child",
            },
            {"label": "Hutchison/MRC Research Centre", "type": "Child"},
            {"label": "MRC Biostatistics Unit", "type": "Child"},
            {"label": "MRC Cognition and Brain Sciences Unit", "type": "Child"},
            {"label": "MRC Epidemiology Unit", "type": "Child"},
            {"label": "MRC Human Nutrition Research", "type": "Child"},
            {"label": "MRC Mitochondrial Biology Unit", "type": "Child"},
            {"label": "MRC Toxicology Unit", "type": "Child"},
            {"label": "Sedgwick Museum of Earth Sciences", "type": "Child"},
            {
                "label": "The Cambridge Centre for Advanced Research and Education in Singapore",
                "type": "Child",
            },
            {
                "label": "Wellcome/Cancer Research UK Gurdon Institute",
                "type": "Child",
            },
            {
                "label": "Wellcome/MRC Cambridge Stem Cell Institute",
                "type": "Child",
            },
            {
                "label": "Wellcome/MRC Institute of Metabolic Science",
                "type": "Child",
            },
        ],
    }
]
```

---

EDIT: deleted `id` key

Comment: Thanks! That is almost exactly  what I’m after. For the second part is there a way to have only the ‘label’ like ‘Cambridge University Press’ and not the ‘type’ or ‘Id’? Also can you just add a little detail in what you have done so I can read some more and learn? Thanks again.

Comment: @user1222447 See my edit. The code is fairly straightforward - I iterate over all `items` and check if the `chosen` key is set to `True`. If it is, I add it to `result` + all its children.